# CMake FIND_LIBRARY returns wrong path

Tags: cmake

In my project I use differend 3rd libraries, which has been prebuild and added to external-debs subdirectory. I use multiple FindXXX CMake scripts to locate those requirements.

When I try to locate a FreeImage prebuild, CMake find the library successfully but returns always the wrong path lib/libfreeimage.a instead of ./external-debs/freeimage/lib/windows/x64/libfreeimage.a

This is my search operation:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(FREE_IMAGE_LIBRARY 
             NAMES ${LIB_PREFIX}freeimage.${LIB_POSTFIX}
             HINTS ${FREE_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIR}
)
```

And this are my predefintions:

```
# Determine platform architecture
IF (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8 )
  SET(ARCHITECTURE "x64")
ELSE()
  SET(ARCHITECTURE "x86")
ENDIF()

#Determine platform specific include and library 
#paths settings.
IF (WIN32)
   IF (MINGW)
      SET (LIB_PREFIX "lib")
      SET (LIB_POSTFIX "a")
   ELSEIF (MSVC)
      SET (LIB_POSTFIX "lib")
   ENDIF(MINGW)   

   SET (PLATFORM "windows")   
ELSE (UNIX)
   SET (LIB_PREFIX "lib")
   SET (LIB_POSTFIX "a")
   SET (PLATFORM "linux") 
ENDIF (WIN32)

SET(FREE_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external-deps/freeimage/include) 
SET(FREE_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIR  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external-deps/freeimage/lib/${PLATFORM}/${ARCHITECTURE})
```

I use this same code to locate an other pre-build 3rd libary dependency (jsoncpp) located in same external-deps subfolder without any issue.

```
Execute: FindJSON.cmake
-- [INFO]: Find JSON include: ./external-deps/jsoncpp/include
-- [INFO]: Find JSON lib: ./external-deps/jsoncpp/lib/windows/x64/libjsoncpp.a
Execute: FindFreeImage.cmake
-- [INFO]: Find FreeImage include: ./external-deps/freeimage/include
-- [INFO]: Find FreeImage lib: /lib/libfreeimage.a
```

I'am using CMake 2.8.x on windows platform.
Has anyone an idea why CMake sometimes return a wrong library path?

Comment: I suggest using Process Monitor (from SysInternals) to spy on cmake while it's running and see exactly what paths it is looking into.  Maybe that will help point out where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like CMake has found another installation of the library in your MinGW environment. This might be a false positive.

Use `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` if you want to force CMake to use a library from a specific directory:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(FREE_IMAGE_LIBRARY 
         NAMES ${LIB_PREFIX}freeimage.${LIB_POSTFIX}
         HINTS ${FREE_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIR}
         NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

Take a look at the [CMake command reference](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) to get some insight on the subtle rules that drive the path resolution in `find_library`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the NO_DEFAULT_PATH option. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember about `find_library()` is that CMake does not do the search if it thinks it already knows where the library is.  Removing CMake's cache (build directory) can often help.